# Where can i find the Expenses Data Map

Tags: simcity-2013

When my city ran out of money the game switched the view to a data map of where my budget was going to geographically. I can't find how to toggle that view manually, outside of running out of money.

[image]

Comment: are you sure that this was a separate data map? A full list of data maps can be found by clicking on the 'All Data Maps' button in the bottom right of the screen, which doesn't have an expenses data map on it. Could it have been the land value map?

Comment: @kalina I added a screenshot

Comment: After checking everything, I'm fairly certain that this is the only way to see the cost of each individual building.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This (unfortunately) is not one of the data maps available via the "All Data Maps" button.